# Install Trusted root certificate authority certificate via GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, certificate-authority

We have a Win2k8 as a Domain Controller in a domain with workstations that run Windows XP. I would like to be able to install via GPO a new trusted root certificate authority certificate that I've generated myself.

I've created a GPO, imported the certificate in Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Public Key Policies\Trusted Root Certificate Authorities and assign the GPO to a group of users. When I do a gpupdate /force on the workstation I can't see the certificate being imported ... even if I reboot the station.

Next, thought that maybe I can do better if I create an intermediate root certificate authority directly on the DC and deploy the intermediate root certificate authority via the GPO. Generated the certificate for the intermediate authority and imported it into the same GPO under Intermediate Certifications Authorities.

Again, ran the gpupdate /force (and rebooted) and checked the workstation. Couldn't see anything either in the Imtermediate or the Root Authorities section.

After a bit of googling managed to find this MSI package [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6315), installed it on two workstations via a GPO and ran the gpupdate /force on the workstations and noticed that the intermediate authority certificate was installed on the workstations but the root CA wasn't.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could try next?

Thanks.

LE. Forgot to mention the Root CA is on a standalone machine, not part of the domain and which I plan to keep offline.

Comment: Which section of which certificate store are you looking at to check it is installed? (I'm doing this to push a CA's certificate out and it appears in the user's "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".)

Comment: I am going into the workstation's Control Panel-> Internet Options->Content->Certificates->Trusted Root Certification Authorities ... and I can't see my CA there.

Answer (score 3):

> I've created a GPO, imported the certificate in Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Public Key Policies\Trusted Root Certificate Authorities and assign the GPO to a group of users

If you are using the "Computer Configuration" policy tree then it will need to be linked to an OU where the *computer accounts* are stored.

If you need to install the certificates into the user's certificate store then `certutil` mioght help. [Microsoft's documentation on certutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc732443.aspx). Use `certutil -installcert <certfile>` (I think that one can be run as a user) or `certutil -addstore -user root <cert file>` in a login script. Note, I haven't tested these, the commands are straight from the help `certutil -v -?`.

Comment: Any idea how to "link to an OU"? Especially if computers aren't in any OU

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem a while ago.
If i remember correctly, this helped us:

1. Computer Configuration > Windows Setting > Public Key Policies >  Double-click Certificate Path Validation Settings, and then click the Stores tab.
2. Select the Define these policy settings check box.
3. Under Per user certificate stores, clear the Allow user trusted root CAs to be used to validate certificates and Allow users to trust peer trust certificates option in the Per User Certificate Stores check boxes.
4. Then use gpupdate /force.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Same thing unfortunately ... This is getting on my nerves now. Thanks.

Comment: Is this certificate also installed on DC?

Comment: Yes ... Installed and working just fine ...

Answer (score 0):

In that case, why do not you also deploy an intermediate CA to issues Certificates? If Standalone CA can contact domain controllers it publishes it's own certificate to appropriate AD containers, which is the default behavior. If auto enrollment is triggered, computers can request certificates. The best way is to use an Enterprise Root and an Issuing CA. Standalone CAs have limitations when comes to enrollment and deployments. Configuration can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx#BKMK_managedomain).
Good Luck!

Comment: The intermediate CA can issue certificates but from what I understand it needs a valid Root CA defined in order for the intermediate CA certificate to be valid. Thanks.

Comment: That is installed when Intermediate or subordinate CA is deployed. It cannot be deployed without the root ca. The process is manual. You can make it an ENt. Subordinate. But there are some other things to clarify. First, to install computer certificates, domain admins have to have local administrator permissions in order to access the local computer store. This is a default but needs to be tested. But if the root certificate and CRLs have not been deployed properly to AD DS, you will run in to problems. With certutil:  certutil -addstore -f root <root.crt>, certutil -addstore -f root <crl.crl>

Comment: To add a subordinate certificate to the intermediate store: certutil -addstore -f CA <subcertfile.crt>. CRL: certutil -addstore -f CA <subcertfile.crl>. In order to publish certificates to AD DS from an offline CA (make sure auto enrollment is possible). certutil -dspublish -f "rootca.crt" RootCA. Use double quotes if the name includes spaces. certutil -dspublish -f subcert.crt SubCA can be used to deploy subordinate CAs to AD DS. Note that if the root ca is used, certificates will be published to both AIA and Certificate Authority containers while subordinate CA published only into AIA.

Comment: In order to publish the CRLs, use certutil -dspublish -f crlfile.crl. If LDAP and other information related to CRLs are not sufficient or cannot be validated, the request may fail. But still you can force the publishing by adding the netBios name at the end of the command. Now the important part. Force the publication if it is not occurring. 1. Run gpupdate /force. 2. Next to that, certutil -pulse. This will initiate the auto enrollment requests.

Comment: Finally, make sure that you understand the containers. 1. All CA certificates will be published into CN=AIA,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,ForestRootDomain (LDAP Distinguished Name). Root CA Certificates are also published into the CN=Certification Authorities,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,ForestRootDomain. Finally, Enterprise CA certificates are published into the CN=NTAuthCertificates,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,ForestRootDomain object (instead container).

Answer (score 0):

slm was close, but instead of unchecking the "`Allow user trusted root CAs to be used to validate certificates`" and `"Allow users to trust peer trust certificates option in the Per User Certificate Stores`" you want to CHECK the boxes.

1. Edit the GPO deploying the certificate
2. In Group Policy Management Editor, Computer Configuration > Windows Setting > Public Key Policies > double-click Certificate Path Validation Settings in the right pane.
3. From the Stores tab, select the Define these policy settings check box.
   Under Per user certificate stores, SELECT the Allow user trusted root CAs to be used to validate certificates and SELECT the Allow users to trust peer trust certificates option in the Per User Certificate Stores check boxes.

Run a `gpupdate/force` on the PC(s) and the cert will be deployed. Also remember to link the GPO to the OU the PC(s) belong to.